# How to upload file using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, upload

I want to attach file through below link. How can I do that using selenium python?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.tascoutsourcing.com/job-openings/quality-assurance-engineer/")

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/button").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[3]/div[3]/div").click()
```

Comment: What are You Try to attach?Can you Specify it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

paul, please try to run below code - I have ran the same code in my system and it is working for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.tascoutsourcing.com/job-openings/quality-assurance-engineer/")

# Click on Apply Button
Apply_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Apply Now']/parent::button")))
action.move_to_element(Apply_btn).click().perform()

time.sleep(2)
Upload_File = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/label/input').send_keys("YourFilePath")
```

Do let me know if it shows error.

Comment: This one worked perfectly. Thanks Swaroop. Could you please let me know from where you got this XPATH driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/label/input')

Comment: Actually I tried finding a `<input type="file">` where usually the file is getting attached/loaded. I just right click on the element and copied the `Xpath` from the dev tool.